# Average value of integer field using views

Tags: views, 6

I set up a multi value cck integer field for rating purposes. It has values

```
 1|good
 2|bad
 3|dont know
```

Users voted like so:

```
3 votes for good
2 votes for bad
4 votes for dont know
```

I want to make an average from all values. In views 3 I checked grouping and set group type average on cck field inside views. Unfortunately, Instead of 1 result I get 3 results - for every value set in cck field. Results are 1, 2 and 3 which is useless. How it is possible to get only one average number? Thank you

EDIT: the average value works the same way using simple text fields. Views group by in views 3 counts only values that are the same. 
And it looks like it is known issue http://drupal.org/node/903768

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) to display the average, but I would suggest going to the [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi) and something like the [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) module which will handle the voting and the averaging for you.